# Are there any relations between Chrome cookies and Laravel Auth?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I haven't seen this kind of strange situation. When Auth login does not work, I delete all cookies on Chrome, and I log in successfully. Laravel auth makes me crazy. Sometimes log-in works well, sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

It's not "Chrome Cookies", it's Laravel Cookies that can cause problem. There can be multiple reasons and you need to debug your code to find the root cause but most common is a faulty `AuthRedirectMiddleware`.This middleware is supposed to redirect users to a /dashboard or /home page by default if they are already logged in based on either the session or the cookies.

So once you login and didn't logout properly and try to re login, you may get unexpected behavior.

To properly debug your code, review everything in the routes, controllers and Auth related middlewares. Try disabling as much code as possible to get the minimum working code which gives you error and that way you can catch the bug causing it.

Let me know in the comments if require further help.

Comment: Yes.. it is a laravel cookie. But the issue was about this.  https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11874 .- replacing

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () { ... });

with

Route::group(['middlewareGroups' => ['web']], function () { ... }); I wonder why laravel does not throw any error messages on that.